# Is there a way to see the values that R doesn't load when you write a line of code?

Tags: r, tibble

Currently I'm working on a case study for a certificate I'm trying to get and I was wondering if there's a way for me to see the remaining rows that R has returned to me.

This is the code that I wrote
`bike_trips %>% count(start_hour, sort = T)`

This is what it returned

```
# A tibble: 24 × 2
   start_hour      n
        <int>  <int>
 1         17 564905
 2         18 490560
 3         16 469811
 4         15 394074
 5         19 364749
 6         14 355982
 7         13 353979
 8         12 345982
 9         11 293882
10         20 256657
# … with 14 more rows
```

How would I go about seeing the 14 more rows if I needed to? Is there a way for me to get R to automatically show me additional rows if needed?

Answer (score 2):

You can see `?tibble::print.tbl` for more information on what arguments can be specified explicitly to the *print method* for "tibbles" (class `tbl`)

```r
(bike_trips 
   %>% count(start_hour, sort = TRUE)
   %>% print(n = Inf)
)
```

If you run into a situation where you want to show all the *columns* you can use `width = Inf`

You could also pipe the results to `View()`.